# step by step process for installing magento extension through ftp

Tags: magento, ftp

Help please, I am not a computer geek, I am a retired nurse trying to make it in the ECommerce world.  I am trying to install an extension for magento for gift cards.  I would like to learn, not just have someone do it for me. The file has been downloaded onto my computer, it was zipped, it is a commercial extension.

There are 4 file folders:  app, js, skin, .DS_Store  When I open the app there are
code, design, etc, locale, and .DS_Store.

The directions are very simple (Maybe great for some but not for me) It says "Unzip the folder", and copy all files to the Magento root folder.

After reading on line, I went to the code file, copied the code to the code on the server, design to the design, etc to the etc, and the locale to the locale.
Logged in to the admin, dumped the cache, logged out, logged back in went to admin, no extension listed.  Help, Tracy

Answer (score 1):

here is the steps for installing extension via ftp:

1. If you're using the Magento compiler - or if you are not sure if you're doing so - please log into the Magento backend and go to System > Tools > Compilation and turn it off.
2. Open the extension ZIP file you downloaded and extract it to a directory on your computer.
3. Upload the extracted folders and files into the root directory of your Magento installation. The root directory of Magento is the folder that contains the directories "app", "js", "skin", "lib" and more.
4. Go to System > Cache Management and click both the 'Flush Magento Cache' as well as the 'Flush Cache Storage' button.
5. Log out of the Magento admin and log back in.
6. If you're using the Magento compiler and had it enabled before installing this extension, go to System > Tools > Compilation and click on 'Run Compilation Process' to re-compile Magento and enable it again by clicking on 'Enable'.